# How to Enable SSL in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, ssl-certificate

I want to use SSL on my server, therefore I have bout an SSL certificate, however the certificate had two parts one of them is the intermediate.

Now how to create the keystore for them?

What I did is the following:

1- chained both certificates and put them in one file. 
2- I have usedd the next command to generate the keystore from the (chained certificate)

```
     keytool -import -alias tomcat -file myCertificate.crt -keystore keystore.p12 -storepass password
```

3- I have add this code into my spring boot:

```
    server.ssl.key-store: C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_231/bin/keystore.p12
    server.ssl.key-store-password: password
    server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
    server.ssl.keyAlias: tomcat
```

But I am still having the next issue:

```
    'Alias name [tomcat] does not identify a key entry'
```

From looking into google I have found out that the issu is my keystore is generating my certificate as  trustedCertEntry instead of PrivateKeyEntry.

How to fix this and what am I missing?

Comment: What if you remove explicit mention of keyAlias entry from config property file

Comment: I get 'Alias name [NULL] does not identify a key entry'

Comment: I think you should inport every certificate in chain individually as from root then intermediate and then your server certificate. And the alias specifies while importing server certificate should be used as keyAlias. This might help  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/18.1/security/java-keystore-preparation.html